# Could a small vortex form off of a large vortex?

Tags: vortex

Is it possible that a small vortex may branch off of a larger vortex?

Note: forgive the elementary drawing, I could not find anything better on the internets.

[image]

Comment: That drawing reminds me of a uterus. Thanks for the laugh, OP.

Comment: Lol thats what my GF said

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It surely does. I have a [real video about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXfkaFmpnL4&index=8&list=PLgUc9kJnDMMExJivT2dWh9dAjdYYUgOFE) ;[image]